# HTML5 Video: как они сделали autoplay на мобильных?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, видео

Как известно, на мобильных устройствах запрещено автовоспроизведение HTML5 Video на уровне ОС. Все пишут, что способа обойти ограничение НЕТ.

Однако, на некоторых сайтах, открываемых через айфон, возникают рекламные блоки с видеороликами, которые воспроизводятся автоматически и вообще ведут себя странно:
— Внезапно возникают и проигрываются автоматически во время прокрутки странички.
— Не разворачиваются во весь экран (как в случае с YouTube iFrame), а остаются в теле страницы.

Пример странички, где периодически возникает видеореклама на iOS: https://m.gazeta.ru/politics/2016/07/11_a_9539045.shtml

Просмотр исходника показал, что видео имеет расширение .webm и управляется скриптом.

Скопировал код этого читерского рекламного модуля:

```html
<div class="adv_mb10">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    if (!puid49_content_type) {
      puid49_content_type = "content";
    }
    if (!puid49_content_counter) {
      var puid49_content_counter = 0;
    }
    puid49_content_counter++;
    var puid49_content_current = puid49_content_type + puid49_content_counter;
    console.log("puid49_content_current: " + puid49_content_current);
    document.writeln('<div id="ban-content-mobile' + puid49_content_counter + '"></div>');
    Adf.banner.showScroll('ban-content-mobile' + puid49_content_counter, {
      'p1': 'bedrc',
      'p2': 'emil',
      'pct': 'b',
      'puid6': 'POLITICS',
      'criteo': 'crslrmm300=1',
      'puid49': puid49_content_current
    });
  </script>
  <div id="ban-content-mobile2">
    <div id="AdFox_banner_10489" style="height: 996px;">
      <script src="//r.webturn.ru/lsanWr;j?176203762" type="text/javascript" async=""></script>
      <div style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; z-index: 90000;">
        <div style="left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%; clip:rect(auto auto auto auto); position:absolute">
          <div style="left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%; height:fixed"></div>
          <div style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; height: 996px;" class="alx-video_branding alxVertical">
            <div style="position:static">
              <a style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%;" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" href="https://ads.adfox.ru/171817/goLink?eid1=0000004657856C2E850D112C96639201&amp;p2=emil&amp;rand=bkhwqyb&amp;p5=dukcu&amp;p1=bedrc&amp;pr=mdmm&amp;hash=a31e7012ed61800a&amp;puid59=1&amp;puid6=POLITICS&amp;puid23=crslrmm300=1&amp;puid49=content2@https%3A%2F%2Fad.adriver.ru%2Fcgi-bin%2Fclick.cgi%3Fsid%3D1%26bt%3D21%26ad%3D590876%26pid%3D2368817%26bid%3D4524211%26bn%3D4524211%26rnd%3D982928255"></a>
              <div style="position: absolute; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0; margin:auto auto auto auto; width: 100%; height: 0; padding-bottom: 56.25%">
                <style>
                  .alx-video,
                  .alx-video * {
                    position: absolute;
                    box-sizing: border-box
                  }
                  .alx-video {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    overflow: hidden
                  }
                  .alx-video__box {
                    position: absolute;
                    background-repeat: no-repeat
                  }
                  .alx-video__controls {
                    overflow: hidden;
                    background-image: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/;
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-size: cover;
                    background-position: 50% 50%;
                  }
                  .alx-video__countdown {
                    color: #ccc;
                    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
                    bottom: 12px;
                    left: 12px;
                    font-size: 12px;
                    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Helv, sans
                  }
                  .alx-video__preload,
                  .alx-video__progress {
                    background: #ccc;
                    opacity: 0.5;
                    left: 0;
                    height: 4px;
                    bottom: 0;
                  }
                  .alx-video__button {
                    top: 50%;
                    left: 50%;
                    margin-left: -32px;
                    margin-top: -32px;
                    display: none
                  }
                  .alx-video__sound {
                    bottom: 12px;
                    right: 8px;
                    display: none
                  }
                  .alx-video__close {
                    top: 0;
                    right: 0;
                    display: none
                  }
                  .alx-video__wait {
                    animation-name: alx-video__wait;
                    animation-duration: 1s;
                    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
                    animation-timing-function: linear;
                    transform: translateZ(0);
                    -webkit-animation-name: alx-video__wait;
                    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
                    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
                    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
                    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0)
                  }
                  @keyframes alx-video__wait {
                    0% {
                      transform: rotate(0deg)
                    }
                    100% {
                      transform: rotate(360deg)
                    }
                  }
                  @-webkit-keyframes alx-video__wait {
                    0% {
                      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)
                    }
                    100% {
                      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)
                    }
                  }
                </style>
                <div class="alx-video">
                  <video class="alx-video__box" src="https://cdn.webturn.ru/m/N/B/NWluo3Pk3al6QiRXm87w/hq/v.m4v" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1400px; height: 788px;"></video>
                  <div class="alx-video__controls" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1400px; height: 788px;">
                    <div class="alx-video__countdown"></div>
                    <div class="alx-video__preload" style="width: 100%; display: none;"></div>
                    <div class="alx-video__progress" style="width: 100%; display: none;"></div>
                    <a class="alx-video__link" href="https://ads.adfox.ru/171817/goLink?eid1=0000004657856C2E850D112C96639201&amp;p2=emil&amp;rand=bkhwqyb&amp;p5=dukcu&amp;p1=bedrc&amp;pr=mdmm&amp;hash=a31e7012ed61800a&amp;puid59=1&amp;puid6=POLITICS&amp;puid23=crslrmm300=1&amp;puid49=content2@https%3A%2F%2Fad.adriver.ru%2Fcgi-bin%2Fclick.cgi%3Fsid%3D1%26bt%3D21%26ad%3D590876%26pid%3D2368817%26bid%3D4524211%26bn%3D4524211%26rnd%3D805127191"
                    style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: transparent;" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"></a>
                    <svg class="alx-video__button alx-video__play" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="display: none;">
                      <circle cy="32" cx="32" r="32" opacity="0.5" fill="#ccc"></circle>
                      <path d="M22 18v30l26-15z" fill="#000"></path>
                    </svg>
                    <svg class="alx-video__button alx-video__pause" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
                      <circle cy="32" cx="32" r="32" opacity="0.5" fill="#ccc"></circle>
                      <path d="M21 19v28h8V19h-8zm14 0v28h8V19h-8z" fill="#000"></path>
                    </svg>
                    <svg class="alx-video__button alx-video__wait" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="display: none;">
                      <circle cy="32" cx="32" r="32" opacity="0.5" fill="#ccc"></circle>
                      <g fill="#000">
                        <path d="M32 16c-8.837 0-16 7.163-16 16s7.163 16 16 16v-7a9 9 0 0 1-9-9 9 9 0 0 1 9-9v-7z" overflow="visible"></path>
                        <path d="M44.855 22.473l-5.633 4.168a9 9 0 0 1 .908 1.523l6.34-2.982a16.06 16.06 0 0 0-1.615-2.707z" overflow="visible" opacity=".15"></path>
                        <path d="M41 32a9 9 0 0 1-.885 3.865l6.317 3.008A15.91 15.91 0 0 0 48 32h-7z" overflow="visible" opacity=".4"></path>
                        <path d="M38.36 38.36a9 9 0 0 1-4.958 2.52l1.09 6.907a15.95 15.95 0 0 0 8.822-4.473L38.36 38.36z" overflow="visible" opacity=".6"></path>
                      </g>
                    </svg>
                    <svg class="alx-video__button alx-video__repeat" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="display: block;">
                      <circle cy="32" cx="32" r="32" opacity="0.5" fill="#ccc"></circle>
                      <path d="M32 16v-3l-10 6 10 6v-2.412A9.412 9.412 0 0 1 41.412 32 9.412 9.412 0 0 1 32 41.412 9.412 9.412 0 0 1 22.588 32H16c0 8.837 7.163 16 16 16s16-7.163 16-16-7.163-16-16-16z" fill="#000"></path>
                    </svg>
                    <svg class="alx-video__sound alx-video__sound-on" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="display: none;">
                      <circle cy="32" cx="32" r="32" opacity="0.5" fill="#ccc"></circle>
                      <path d="M35 15L23 27h-7v10h7l12 12h1V15h-1zm13 3v28h3.076V18H48zm-5 7v14h3.076V25H43zm-5 4v6h3v-6h-3z" fill="#000"></path>
                    </svg>
                    <svg class="alx-video__sound alx-video__sound-off" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="display: none;">
                      <circle cy="32" cx="32" r="32" opacity="0.5" fill="#ccc"></circle>
                      <g fill="#000">
                        <path d="M16 37V27h7l12-12h1v34h-1L23 37"></path>
                        <path d="M37 28l2-2 5 5 5-5 2 2-5 5 5 5-2 2-5-5-5 5-2-2 5-5z"></path>
                      </g>
                    </svg>
                    <svg class="alx-video__close" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
                      <path d="M18 22l4-4 10 10 10-10 4 4-10 10 10 10-4 4-10-10-10 10-4-4 10-10z" fill="#ccc" opacity="0.5"></path>
                    </svg>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div style="position: absolute; left: 10%; width: 80%; height: 36px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 14px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 36px; opacity: 0.7; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; bottom: 17%; display: block;">Подробнее
                <a style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%;" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" href="https://ads.adfox.ru/171817/goLink?eid1=0000004657856C2E850D112C96639201&amp;p2=emil&amp;rand=bkhwqyb&amp;p5=dukcu&amp;p1=bedrc&amp;pr=mdmm&amp;hash=a31e7012ed61800a&amp;puid59=1&amp;puid6=POLITICS&amp;puid23=crslrmm300=1&amp;puid49=content2@https%3A%2F%2Fad.adriver.ru%2Fcgi-bin%2Fclick.cgi%3Fsid%3D1%26bt%3D21%26ad%3D590876%26pid%3D2368817%26bid%3D4524211%26bn%3D4524211%26rnd%3D20366223"></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
          <div style="top:0; left: 0; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 36px; background-color: #fff; font-size: 14px; color: #000; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 36px; opacity: 0.7; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased">Реклама
            <a style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%;"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
          <div style="bottom:0; left: 0; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 36px; background-color: #fff; font-size: 14px; color: #000; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 36px; opacity: 0.7; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased">Потяните, чтобы пропустить
            <a style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%;"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <iframe id="AdFox_iframe_10489" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="1" height="1" style="position: absolute;"></iframe>
  </div>

</div>
```

Итак, ВОПРОС. Autoplay на мобильных: как они это сделали? Как обошли ограничения?

Comment: Может все дело в использовании SSI?

Comment: Можно попробовать изучить что делает этот скрипт http://cdn.webturn.ru/alx/rasv1.js?612115519